# How to zoom in/out desktop icons on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, zoom

I would like to zoom in/out Desktop icons on Ubuntu 16.04. I don't know how to do it ( like Windows: Just use Ctrl+Mouse Wheel to zoom).

Please any one know about it help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if you can zoom with mouse but the icon size can be set in Display or config file. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/83099/how-to-change-desktop-icon-size

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 16.04 runs the Compiz compositor, which enables desktop zoom. If not already installed, you can use the Compiz settings manager to enable and assign a keyboard combination of your choosing. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/593656/zoom-desktop-tool-for-ubuntu-14 for the steps complete with screenshots (instructions for 16.04 are listed below those for 14.04).

Here is a summary of the steps from that article:

- Open a terminal and type `apt install compizconfig-settings-manager`. The apt tool will install the settings manager. You can close the terminal.
- Click on the Ubuntu icon at the top-left corner of desktop, type compiz and then click on the Compiz icon that appears
- Read the warning window that opens, then click on OK
- Click on Accessibility --> Enhanced Zoom Desktop --> Tick the box
- Click on Enhanced Zoom Desktop
- Click on Zoom In Key --> Disabled
- Tick the box Enabled
- Now you can define your own keyboard combo. Click on Grab Key Combination.
- Press together `Ctrl + F7` and click on OK
- Click on Zoom Out Key --> Disabled
- Tick on the box Enabled
- Click on Grab Key Combination
- Press together `Ctrl + F6` and click on OK
- Close the window

From now on, to Zoom In press `Ctrl + F7` and to Zoom Out press `Ctrl + F6`. Based on the comments, you may need to log out and in (or just restart).